# How can i fix enroll account action in iOS13

Tags: xamarin.forms, ios13, intune

I installed iPadOS(iOS13.1) in iPad.
Then my Intune managed app enrollment action stop working.
I tried to debug this app, and found error message(debug output window).
How can i fix it?

VisualStudio2019
Xamarin.Forms
Microsoft.Intune.MAM.Xamarin.iOS 11.0.13

Enrollment action is only this code.

```cs
using Microsoft.Intune.MAM;
string UPN = "user@sometenant.onmicrosoft.com";
IntuneMAMEnrollmentManager.Instance.LoginAndEnrollAccount(UPN);
```

ERROR: createEncodedCachedResponseAndRequestForXPCTransmission - Invalid protocol-property list - CFURLRequestRef. protoProps={
    context = "";
}
ADD: failed to create cache dictionary at path=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/92260F8D-5EE4-44D1-B853-178A8DB0A770/Library/Caches/***App Name***/MAMURLCache. key=0x280047bd0
Thread finished:  #6

Comment: does it work before update to 13?

Comment: Yes. In iOS12 it worked fine same code, same setting.